# Reusing media projection Intent on Android 14

Tags: android, android-mediaprojection, android-14

I have an Android screen recording app. In my app the user can start a screen recording directly in the app, as well as via a button in a notification (bound to a foreground service).

To start a recording I retrieve the intent for creating media projections via the screen recording system dialog:
`startActivityForResult(activity, mediaProjectionManager.createScreenCaptureIntent(), requestId)`

This intent is later used to create a MediaProjection, which is again used to acquire a `VirtualDisplay` for the screen recording.

In order to avoid having to start a screen recording system dialog every time the user starts a recording via the notification from my foreground service, I save the original `Intent` for creating media projections in the service and then simply reuse that `Intent`. This worked fine up to Android 14 (API 34).

During my testing with the Android 14 Preview I found out that this does not seem to be possible anymore. According to the exception thrown it is not allowed anymore to retrieve a `MediaProjection` with the same `Intent` OR create multiple virtual displays with the same `MediaProjection`.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.recording.app.staging, PID: 19029
                 java.lang.SecurityException: Don't re-use the resultData to retrieve the same projection instance, and don't use a token that has timed out. Don't take multiple captures by invoking MediaProjection#createVirtualDisplay multiple times on the same instance.
                    at android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull(Parcel.java:3057)
                    at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:3041)
                    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:3024)
                    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2966)
                    at android.hardware.display.IDisplayManager$Stub$Proxy.createVirtualDisplay(IDisplayManager.java:1425)
                    at android.hardware.display.DisplayManagerGlobal.createVirtualDisplay(DisplayManagerGlobal.java:643)
                    at android.hardware.display.DisplayManager.createVirtualDisplay(DisplayManager.java:1134)
                    at android.media.projection.MediaProjection.createVirtualDisplay(MediaProjection.java:247)
                    at android.media.projection.MediaProjection.createVirtualDisplay(MediaProjection.java:216)
                    at com.recording.app.model.service.recording.resource.MediaProjectionResource.createVirtualDisplay(MediaProjectionResource.kt:39)
                 Caused by: android.os.RemoteException: Remote stack trace:
                    at com.android.server.media.projection.MediaProjectionManagerService$MediaProjection.isValid(MediaProjectionManagerService.java:1081)
                    at com.android.server.display.DisplayManagerService.createVirtualDisplayInternal(DisplayManagerService.java:1447)
                    at com.android.server.display.DisplayManagerService.-$$Nest$mcreateVirtualDisplayInternal(DisplayManagerService.java:0)
                    at com.android.server.display.DisplayManagerService$BinderService.createVirtualDisplay(DisplayManagerService.java:3706)
                    at android.hardware.display.IDisplayManager$Stub.onTransact(IDisplayManager.java:730)com.android.server.media.projection.MediaProjectionManagerService$MediaProjection.isValid(MediaProjectionManagerService.java:1081)

...
```

Is there still a way to allow my users to only grant the screen recording permission once and then to directly start a recording (as long as my service was not killed)?

Maybe it is possible to keep and reuse a single `VirtualDisplay`, but that also does not seem like a good solution because the display would mirror the real display even if there was no recording going on, wasting resources.

If that does not work, my only remaining option is to always ask the user for permission. But I am also unsure whether that works when the user has opened a different app and only wants to start the recording via notification.

Did I miss something? Any insights are greatly appreciated!

#### Update

After some more testing:

- Reusing the same `Intent` to retrieve multiple `MediaProjection`s is not possible
- Reusing a single `MediaProjection` instance to get multiple `VirtualDisplay`s also seems impossible
- It is possible to reuse a single `VirtualDisplay` instance to do multiple recordings, but seems hacky

#### Outcome

It is possible to do multiple recordings with a single `VirtualDisplay` by always updating the target surface using

`virtualDispaly.surface = newRecordingSurface`

However, this seems hacky and not intended because the system UI will show that the app is recording the screen as long as the `VirtualDisplay` is active. So even if my app is not "really" capturing the screen (because no target surface is set for the `VirtualDisplay`) the system UI still shows like it is.

This would look very concerning for a user and the user can also just stop the screen capture at which point the `VirtualDisplay` seems to be broken.
Therefore, I decided to **remove** the functionality, to start a recording from my foreground service, until I find a better option.

Comment: Did you happen to find a different solution? I am running into the same issue.

Comment: Kinda. As a workaround I am now launching a transparent activity everytime the user clicks on the record button. This transparent activity then requests the screen recording permission, which is then used to create a media projection and virtual display.
This works surprisingly smooth and the user doesn't notice it. For them it looks like the screen recording permission dialog just pops up like a system dialog.
Still, I would have prefered a proper solution...

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems to be an intended change, see https://developer.android.com/about/versions/14/behavior-changes-14#media-projection-consent. Weirdly enough this may drive apps allowing users to take "screenshots" by using very short MediaProjection sessions to just record the screen all the time since a lot of users perceive the permission request every time as too much of a hassle...

Comment: Yeah, I think a lot of apps will simply remove screenshotting from their apps now. We added it because it was convenient for the user via our notification controls. But now it's either permanently record the screen (on Android 14 the user sees when your app is recording the screen), which is just horrible from a privacy point of view,  or make it extremely cumbersome by always requesting permission or removing the feature.
The alternative for the user is to press some hardware buttons and have a screenshot. That's a lot easier